# Apache SetEnv not working as expected with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, flask

In a flask application I wrote, I make use of an external library which can be configured using environment variables. Note: I wrote this external library myself. So I *could* make changes if necessary. When running from the command line an running the flask server with:

```
# env = python virtual environment
ENV_VAR=foo ./env/bin/python myapp/webui.py
```

it all woks as expected. But after deploying it to apache, and using `SetEnv` it does *not* work anymore. In fact, printing out `os.environ` to `stderr` (so it shows up in the apache logs reveals, that the `wsgi` process seems to be in a very different environment (for one, `os.environ['PWD']` seems to be *way* off. In fact, it points to my development folder.

To help identifying the problem, following are the relevant parts of the application as a standalone hello-world app. The error output, and observations are at the very end of the post.

#### App folder layout:

Python app:

```
.
├── myapp.ini
├── setup.py
└── testenv
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── model
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── webui.py
```

Apache folder (`/var/www/michel/testenv`):

```
.
├── env
│   ├── [...]
├── logs
│   ├── access.log
│   └── error.log
└── wsgi
└── app.wsgi
```

#### myapp.ini

```
[app]
somevar=somevalue
```

#### setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="testenv",
    version='1.0dev1',
    description="A test app",
    long_description="Hello World!",
    author="Some Author",
    author_email="author@example.com",
    license="BSD",
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires = [
      'flask',
      ],
    packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests.*", "tests"]),
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

#### testenv/**init**.py

```
# empty
```

#### testenv/model/**init**.py

```
from os.path import expanduser, join, exists
from os import getcwd, getenv, pathsep
import logging
import sys

__version__ = '1.0dev1'

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def find_config():
    """
    Searches for an appropriate config file. If found, return the filename, and
    the parsed search path
    """

    path = [getcwd(), expanduser('~/.mycompany/myapp'), '/etc/mycompany/myapp']
    env_path = getenv("MYAPP_PATH")
    config_filename = getenv("MYAPP_CONFIG", "myapp.ini")
    if env_path:
        path = env_path.split(pathsep)

    detected_conf = None
    for dir in path:
        conf_name = join(dir, config_filename)
        if exists(conf_name):
            detected_conf = conf_name
            break
    return detected_conf, path

def load_config():
    """
    Load the config file.
    Raises an OSError if no file was found.
    """
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

    conf, path = find_config()
    if not conf:
        raise OSError("No config file found! Search path was %r" % path)

    parser = SafeConfigParser()
    parser.read(conf)
    LOG.info("Loaded settings from %r" % conf)
    return parser

try:
    CONF = load_config()
except OSError, ex:
    # Give a helpful message instead of a scary stack-trace
    print >>sys.stderr, str(ex)
    sys.exit(1)
```

#### testenv/webui.py

```
from testenv.model import CONF

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World %s!" % CONF.get('app', 'somevar')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debue = True
    app.run()
```

#### Apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testenv-test.my.fq.dn
    ServerAlias testenv-test

    WSGIDaemonProcess testenv user=michel threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/michel/testenv/wsgi/app.wsgi
    SetEnv MYAPP_PATH /var/www/michel/testenv/config

    <Directory /var/www/michel/testenv/wsgi>
        WSGIProcessGroup testenv
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/michel/testenv/logs/error.log
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/www/michel/testenv/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

#### app.wsgi

```
activate_this = '/var/www/michel/testenv/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

from os import getcwd
import logging, sys

from testenv.webui import app as application

# You may want to change this if you are using another logging setup
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOG.debug('Current path: {0}'.format(getcwd()))

# Application config
application.debug = False

# vim: set ft=python :
```

## Error and observations

This is the output of the apache error log.

```
[Thu Jan 26 10:48:15 2012] [error] No config file found! Search path was ['/home/users/michel', '/home/users/michel/.mycompany/myapp', '/etc/mycompany/myapp']
[Thu Jan 26 10:48:15 2012] [error] [client 10.115.192.101] mod_wsgi (pid=17946): Target WSGI script '/var/www/michel/testenv/wsgi/app.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Jan 26 10:48:15 2012] [error] [client 10.115.192.101] mod_wsgi (pid=17946): SystemExit exception raised by WSGI script '/var/www/michel/testenv/wsgi/app.wsgi' ignored.
[Thu Jan 26 10:48:15 2012] [error] [client 10.115.192.101] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jan 26 10:48:15 2012] [error] [client 10.115.192.101]   File "/var/www/michel/testenv/wsgi/app.wsgi", line 10, in <module>
[Thu Jan 26 10:48:15 2012] [error] [client 10.115.192.101]     from testenv.webui import app as application
[Thu Jan 26 10:48:15 2012] [error] [client 10.115.192.101]   File "/var/www/michel/testenv/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/testenv-1.0dev1-py2.6.egg/testenv/webui.py", line 1, in <module>
[Thu Jan 26 10:48:15 2012] [error] [client 10.115.192.101]     from testenv.model import CONF
[Thu Jan 26 10:48:15 2012] [error] [client 10.115.192.101]   File "/var/www/michel/testenv/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/testenv-1.0dev1-py2.6.egg/testenv/model/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
[Thu Jan 26 10:48:15 2012] [error] [client 10.115.192.101]     sys.exit(1)
[Thu Jan 26 10:48:15 2012] [error] [client 10.115.192.101] SystemExit: 1
```

My first observation is that the environment variable `MYAPP_PATH` does not appear in `os.environ` (this is not visible in this output, but I tested it, and it's not there!). As such, the config "resolver" falls back to the default path.

And my second observation is the search path for the config file lists `/home/users/michel` as return value of `os.getcwd()`. I was actually expecting something inside `/var/www/michel/testenv`.

My instinct tells me, that the way I am doing config resolution is not right. Mainly because code is executed at import-time. This leads me to the idea, that maybe the config-resolution code is executed *before* the WSGI environment is properly set up. Am I onto something there?

### Short discussion / tangential question

How would *you* do the config resolution in this case? Given that the "model" sub-folder is in reality an external module, which should also work in non-wsgi applications, and should provide a method to configure a database connection.

Personally, I like the way I search for config files while still being able to override it. Only, the fact that code is executed at import-time is making my spider-senses tingling like crazy. The rationale behind this: Configuration handling is completely hidden (abstraction-barrier) by fellow developers using this module, and it "just works". They just need to import the module (with an existing config-file of course) and can jump right in without knowing any DB details. This also gives them an easy way to work with different databases (dev/test/deployment) and switch between them easily.

Now, inside mod_wsgi it does not anymore :(

#### Update:

Just now, to test my above idea, I changed the `webui.py` to the following:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify(os.environ)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debue = True
    app.run()
```

The output on the webpage is the following:

```
{
    LANG: "C",
    APACHE_RUN_USER: "www-data",
    APACHE_PID_FILE: "/var/run/apache2.pid",
    PWD: "/home/users/michel/tmp/testenv",
    APACHE_RUN_GROUP: "www-data",
    PATH: "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin",
    HOME: "/home/users/michel/"
}
```

This shows the same environment as the one seen by other debugging methods. So my initial though was wrong. But now I realised something stranger yet. `os.environment['PWD']` is set to the folder where I have my development files. This is not at *all* where the application is running. Stranger yet, `os.getcwd()` returns `/home/users/michel`? This is inconsistent with what I see in `os.environ`. Should it not be the same as `os.environ['PWD']`?

The most important problem remains though: Why is the value set by apache's `SetEnv` (`MYAPP_PATH` in this case) not found in `os.environ`?

Comment: It almost looks like you did more work writing this question than on your actual app. Great write up :)

Comment: @Cerin: I assume this is helpful to other people. So I try to write my questions as detailed as possible. Maybe someone learns something from both the question *and* the answer ^_^

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Note that the WSGI environment is passed upon each request to the application in the `environ` argument of the application object. This environment is totally unrelated to the process environment which is kept in `os.environ`. The `SetEnv` directive has no effect on `os.environ` and there is no way through Apache configuration directives to affect what is in the process environment.

So you have to do something else other than `getenviron` or `os.environ['PWD']` to get the `MY_PATH` from apache.

Flask adds the wsgi environ to the request, not `app.environ`, it is done by the underlaying `werkzeug`. So on each request to the application, apache will add the `MYAPP_CONF` key and youll access it wherever you can access request it seems as, `request.environ.get('MYAPP_CONFIG')` for example.

Answer (score 12):

@rapadura answer is correct in that you don't have direct access to the `SetEnv` values in your Apache config, but you can work around it.

If you add a wrapper around `application` in your `app.wsgi` file you can set the `os.environ` on each request. See the following modified `app.wsgi` for an example:

```
activate_this = '/var/www/michel/testenv/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

from os import environ, getcwd
import logging, sys

from testenv.webui import app as _application

# You may want to change this if you are using another logging setup
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOG.debug('Current path: {0}'.format(getcwd()))

# Application config
_application.debug = False

def application(req_environ, start_response):
    environ['MYAPP_CONF'] = req_environ['MYAPP_CONF']
    return _application(req_environ, start_response)
```

If you have set more environment variables in your Apache config, then you need to explicitly set each of them in the `application` wrapper function.

Comment: I use a convention for the variable names, like MYAPP_FOO, MYAPP_BAR, then in the wrapper I can use a loop. Works well for apps with many config options.

`_env = {k.replace('MYAPP_',''): v for k,v in req_environ.items() if k.startswith('MYAPP_')}`
`os.environ.update(_env)`

Comment: Or you can just put the variables in the `.wsgi` file rather than in the apache config.

Comment: @BenWhaley the `.wsgi` file is usually stored in a version control system along with the application itself, which means it is not ideal for config values that are "secret" or unique to the environment they are running in (eg. db/test/prod have different DB username/password). The use of environment variables means you can check out the same code in each environment (dev/test/prod) and assuming the environment variables are set correctly it should just run. This is why they are stored in the apache config, not the `.wsgi` file.

Comment: I think it just depends how you manage your config. If you have a config management solution, the wsgi file can be a template and the CM tool just fills in the variables. Point is that there are many ways to handle this.

Comment: @BenWhaley Most PAAS provides assume you are using environment variables, which is why it has become the norm. If you really want to use some sort of template (which I would advise against), then the config values would be better stored with your other config values (ie. where the Flask app.config stuff is handled) and not in the `.wsig` file.