# wsgi environment variable not being read

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I am trying to deploy a python/flask app with http using Ubuntu 16/Apache2. The app utilizes [Flask-Dance](http://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/google.html) for OAuth, which requires that I set the environment variable OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT = 1. According to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016504/apache-setenv-not-working-as-expected-with-mod-wsgi) I should set the variable using a wrapper in my wsgi file. My wsgi file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
from os import environ

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/baseball_catalog/")

from baseball_catalog import app as _application
_application.secret_key = 'supersekrit'

def application(req_environ, start_response):
    environ['OAUTH_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
    return _application(req_environ, start_response)
```

However, I am still getting this error

```
InsecureTransportError: (insecure_transport) OAuth 2 MUST utilize https.
```

in my apache error.log file. What am I missing? Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @TallChuck for catching that I made a mistake writing the variable name.

Comment: you have the variable name as `OAUTH_INSECURE_TRANSPORT`, not `OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT`

Comment: Thank you @TallChuck! And here I was thinking the answer would be much more complicated...